# Sublime Text 3 cannot find my shell PATH so none of my linters work

Tags: sublimetext3

I get this error when I open Sublime Text 3 (build 3103):

SublimeLinter could not determine your shell PATH. It is unlikely that any linters will work. 
Please see the troubleshooting guide for info on how to debug PATH problems.

I am using OS X and use virtual env and virtual env wrapper.

I am trying to get Sublime-Linter-pylint to work, but I get this error even before that package is installed.

This is what I get from debug console:

```
startup, version: 3103 osx x64 channel: stable
executable: /Applications/Sublime Text.app/Contents/MacOS/Sublime Text
working dir: /
packages path: /Users/x7to/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Packages
state path: /Users/x7to/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Local
zip path: /Applications/Sublime Text.app/Contents/MacOS/Packages
zip path: /Users/x7to/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Installed Packages
ignored_packages: ["GitGutter", "Vintage"]
pre session restore time: 0.246384
first paint time: 0.289856
startup time: 0.302495
reloading plugin Default.block
reloading plugin Default.comment
reloading plugin Default.convert_syntax
reloading plugin Default.copy_path
reloading plugin Default.delete_word
reloading plugin Default.detect_indentation
reloading plugin Default.duplicate_line
reloading plugin Default.echo
reloading plugin Default.exec
reloading plugin Default.fold
reloading plugin Default.font
reloading plugin Default.goto_line
reloading plugin Default.history_list
reloading plugin Default.indentation
reloading plugin Default.kill_ring
reloading plugin Default.mark
reloading plugin Default.new_templates
reloading plugin Default.open_context_url
reloading plugin Default.open_file_settings
reloading plugin Default.open_in_browser
reloading plugin Default.pane
reloading plugin Default.paragraph
reloading plugin Default.paste_from_history
reloading plugin Default.profile
reloading plugin Default.profile_syntax_definition
reloading plugin Default.quick_panel
reloading plugin Default.run_syntax_tests
reloading plugin Default.save_on_focus_lost
reloading plugin Default.scroll
reloading plugin Default.set_unsaved_view_name
reloading plugin Default.side_bar
reloading plugin Default.sort
reloading plugin Default.swap_line
reloading plugin Default.switch_file
reloading plugin Default.symbol
reloading plugin Default.transform
reloading plugin Default.transpose
reloading plugin Default.trim_trailing_white_space
reloading plugin CSS.css_completions
reloading plugin Diff.diff
reloading plugin HTML.encode_html_entities
reloading plugin HTML.html_completions
reloading plugin Python.syntax_test_python
reloading plugin 0_package_control_loader.00-package_control
reloading plugin 0_package_control_loader.02-bz2
reloading plugin Package Control.1_reloader
reloading plugin Package Control.2_bootstrap
reloading plugin Package Control.Package Control
reloading plugin SublimeLinter-pylint.linter
SublimeLinter: pylint linter loaded 
reloading plugin Jedi - Python autocompletion.__init__
reloading plugin SublimeLinter.commands
reloading plugin SublimeLinter.sublimelinter
plugins loaded
SublimeLinter: debug mode: on 
SublimeLinter: temp directory: /var/folders/0h/r1z0zq4x74x_fq69hhhthv7c2307w3/T/SublimeLinter3-x7to 
SublimeLinter: find_python(version='3', script=None, module=None) 
SublimeLinter: find_python: requested version = {'major': 3, 'minor': None} 
SublimeLinter: user shell: /bin/bash 
SublimeLinter: shell timed out after 20 seconds, executing ('/bin/bash', '-l', '-c', 'echo "__SUBL_PATH__${PATH}__SUBL_PATH__"') 
SublimeLinter: Could not parse shell PATH output:
<empty> 
error: SublimeLinter could not determine your shell PATH. It is unlikely that any linters will work. 

Please see the troubleshooting guide for info on how to debug PATH problems.
SublimeLinter: computed PATH using /bin/bash:
/usr/local/bin/pylint


SublimeLinter: find_posix_python: python3 => None 
SublimeLinter: find_posix_python: python3 => None 
SublimeLinter: find_posix_python: python => None 
SublimeLinter: find_python: system python = None 
SublimeLinter: find_python: <= (None, None, None, None) 
SublimeLinter: no python 3 available to augment sys.path 
Package Control: Skipping automatic upgrade, last run at 2016-03-18 12:38:03, next run at 2016-03-18 13:38:03 or after
```

I have read many troubleshooting guides and have tried all different configurations of paths and nothing works. I still get that error and my linter does not work. It worked for several months until about two weeks ago and then it suddenly stopped working. I cannot determine if anything changed.

I ran the bash command manually and it worked almost immediately:

```
$ /bin/bash -l -c 'echo "__SUBL_PATH__${PATH}__SUBL_PATH__"'
running awsme
__SUBL_PATH__/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_65.jdk/Contents/Home/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_65.jdk/Contents/Home/bin:~/bin:/Applications/apache-jmeter-2.13/bin:~/bin:/Applications/apache-jmeter-2.13/bin__SUBL_PATH__
```

What is wrong?

Comment: Where does "*running awsme*" come from?

Comment: That is just a custom script that connects me with AWS. 

Looks like I solved this problem using the path variables in the sublime configuration. It still does not pull the paths from bash, but at least the linter works now.